# How to display Thumbnail in Radio App, List, Expand And Categories From (Hosting server) Admin Panel?

Tags: java, android

Glide.with(context)
.load(sharedPref.getBaseUrl() + "/upload/category/" + c.category_image.replace(" ", "%20"))
.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_thumbnail)
.thumbnail(0.3f)
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
.into(vItem.imgCategory);

Now Displaying a Icon from Local folder

Now Displaying a Icon from Local folder but
i Want to display thumbnail from Online Admin Panel Library.

Answer (score 0):

You can user Coil library for that I have attached like of post for xml to work on you can refer that to use it in you app. [The link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-coil-image-loader-library-in-android-apps/)

Comment: Thanks For Answer, My Project In Java Not Kotlin, Your Answer preferred for Kotlin.

Comment: @PBINDIA Here is link for java you can use coil for kotlin and java :- https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/java_compatibility/